# WebBrowser object couldn't show text (.txt) file properly in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, text-files

I'm writing an application with C# Winforms and using a `WebBrowser` object to display text files.

I have a `DataGridView` which shows me all the files I have added before, and every click on a Data Row activates `webBrowser.Navigate(FilePath)`.

The thing is **it shows me the text file properly in the first time** after clicking the first .txt in the DataGrid, but after it its just writing me:

> the page could not be displayed

...in the `WebBrowser` panel.

I tried to added this code before it loaded another text file:

```
                    webBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
```

but it doesn't help.

**Edit:**  After clicking on a `RowCell` in `DataGridView` I'm calling this function with the file full path:

```
    private byte LoadDoc(string sFileName)
    {
        fInfo = new FileInfo(sFileName);
        if (fInfo.Extension.ToUpper().StartsWith(".TXT"))
        {
            pnlBrowser.Visible = true;
            webBrowser.Navigate(fInfo.FullName);

            if (webBrowser.Document != null)
            {
                 webBrowser.Document.Encoding = "iso-8859-8-i";
            }   
            return 0;
        }
     }
```

**Edit:** This is the `DataGridView` `CellClick` code:

```
    private void dgvDetails_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dgvDetails.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                DataGridViewCell myCell = dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(myCell.Value) == true)
                    myCell.Value = false;
                else
                    myCell.Value = true;

            }
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            txtFileDesc.Text = dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90FILDS"].Value.ToString();

            // clear temp values
            ClearTempVals();

            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            // store temp values in case update required
            sd_CustNum = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90CSTID"].Value);
            sd_ProcId = Convert.ToInt64(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90CSTID"].Value);
            sd_ActivityId = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90CSTID"].Value);
            sd_FileId = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90FILID"].Value);
            sd_FileDesc = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90FILDS"].Value);
            sd_Mutag = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90MUTAG"].Value);
            sd_Dealer = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90DEAL"].Value);
            sd_DocNum = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90DOCID"].Value);
            sd_DocType = Convert.ToByte(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90DOCTP"].Value);
            sd_ScanDate = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90OPDT"].Value);
            sd_ScanTime = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90OPTM"].Value);
            sd_ScanUser = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90OPUS"].Value);
            sd_SibatIdkun = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90UPSBA"].Value);
            sd_IdkunDate = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90UPDT"].Value);
            sd_IdkunTime = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90UPTM"].Value);
            sd_IdkunUser = Convert.ToString(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90UPUS"].Value);



            if (LoadDoc(dgvDetails.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["C90FILID"].Value.ToString()) > 0)
            {
                ClearTempVals();
                _ErrMsg = "Error Accrues";
                return;
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            BtnSave.Enabled = true;
            btnDelete.Enabled = true;

        }
        else // trying to sort columns by clicking headers
        {
            // clear webbrowser and selected rows
            webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
            dgvDetails.ClearSelection();
            dgvDetails.CurrentCell = null;
            txtFileDesc.Text = "";
            BtnSave.Enabled = false;
            ClearTempVals();
        }

    }
```

**Edit:** This is what `WebBrowser object` contains (in debug mode) after calling the second text file:

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: After a click on a `DataGridView` I'm just calling a function `LoadDoc` which uses the `WebBrowser` object. I edited my original question.

Comment: First of all: stop swallowing exceptions! Remove the try/catch block too see what happens.

Comment: @Micke, Ok you are right, I removed the try\catch block, but as expected nothing happens and it's still not working.

Comment: Are all the text files stored in the same location/folder as the one you are able to display successfully? What if you make multiple copies of the that displays OK. Can you display those (copies) as well?

Comment: What if you call `webBrowser.Refresh()` after `Navigate()`? Does it change anything?

Comment: Considering we're no closer to solving what should be rather straight-forward problem, I think you should post your handler code for `RowCell` click where you call `LoadDoc()`.  Just in case your doing all this in a _worker thread; neglected planetary alignment_ or _forgot to sacrifice a chicken_.  Cheers

Comment: Yes, all the text files stores in the same folder. The problem is that the same text file couldn't shows at all after clicking it second or third time...Also, `webBrowser.Refresh()` does not help. I have added a picture of the `WebBrowser` object in debug mode which shows the problem.

Comment: _[You should not use `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents).  It can lead to _re-entrancy_ in your UI-handlers. Plus it's unkind to kittens

Comment: If in your click-handler, you are calling `LoadDoc()`, then looping around with `Application.DoEvents();` - then **there is your problem right there**

Comment: I added the `RowCell click` code

Comment: Thanks.  Just do a `this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor` and remove the prior 2 lines including the `DoEvents()`.  Also, what's the `Thread.Sleep()` for?

Comment: @MickyDuncan I added this `Thread.Sleep()` to add small delay before I enables the buttons in the form, in order to prevent clicking errors from the user.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I deleted `DoEvents()` but still nothing.,,